# WPF Treeview updating

Tags: xaml, binding, treeview, observablecollection

I have to treeviews in a window. Both treeview are bound to an observable collection "ReportStructure".

Both treeviews shows a treelevel hierarcical structure of the observable collection. I use one treeview, T1. to select the nodes i want to show in the second treeview T2.

The first treeview has checkboxes on each leaf and when i check or uncheck a leaf it is shown or hidden in T2. In order for me to do that i have to requery the bound collectionview like this

```
  var IEquip = from eq in Report.Document.InspectionData.Equipments where eq.PartData.ReportIncluded = true
                     orderby eq.PartData.Order ascending
                     select eq;


        EquipmentView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(IEquip);
        EquipmentView.SortDescriptions.Add(
       new SortDescription("PartData.Order", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

The "ReportStructure" above is Report.Document.InspectionData.Equipments.

My problem is that when i requery the datacontext for T2 all nodes in T1 are collapsed

I my XAML i have set updatesourcetrigger explicit but it still collapses.

```
    <TreeView Grid.Row="5" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ReportStructure, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
```

Cloning would be a solution, but then i loose the possiblity to update T2 from the information in T1 without passing the clone

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the TreeViewItem does not remember whether it were previously expanded whenever you perform your requery?  Consider adding an "IsExpanded" property to your 'Equipment' class, and then have the TreeViewitem's IsExpanded property bind to the viewmodel's property.